# Is there any way to add a blank line in the beginning of a Facebook comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Sometimes I'd like to have empty lines at the beginning of my comments on Facebook.  However Facebook strips all the attempts I've made so far.

- Shift + Enter
- Alt + 32, then Enter
- Alt + 255, then Enter
- Alt + 0160, then Enter

None work.
Is it possible?

---

**EDIT - June 2016**

The accepted answer does exactly what I was looking for by making comments start on a new line, but has unexpected (or expected) repercussions on other versions of Facebook.

Facebook's full Web App

> [image]

Facebook's Windows App

> [image]

Facebook's Android App

> [image]

What I didn't realize is these other apps **already** format the comments the way I was looking to format them on the Web App. I can see why they might not want consistency on the web... a line break for every comment takes up a lot of space on the page... but let's be consistent Facebook! :-D

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568624/inserting-an-empty-facebook-comment?noredirect=1#comment62629222_37568624

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by inserting a soft hyphen and then adding a newline.

To insert a soft hyphen:
Hold the (left) ALT key and type 0173 from the Numeric keypad (first make sure you've unlocked it, press Num Lock if not), release the ALT key. Alternatively, find it in the Character Map (if on windows, press the Windows Key + R, type charmap) and copy-paste it.

To insert a newline, hold Shift and press Enter.

[image: The result]

Comment: How to do this from MAC?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have blank line in the beginning in a comment. There is no such feature available as of now. It will always collapse the blank line(s) not only in the beginning even in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead *Combining Grapheme Joiner* character `Unicode: 034F` which has no visible glyph.

Should be ignored by most applications, but still circumvent trimming of empty rows.

[image]